# How to get required fields as a list of json by DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to acieve simple nested json.
serializer.py

```
class CurrencyMasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CurrencyMaster
        fields = ["id", "name"]
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "USD - United States Dollar"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "EUR - Euro Members"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "JPY - Japan Yen"
    },
```

This is I got response by postman. But I expect output like below,

```
{
    "country-codes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "USD - United States Dollar"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "EUR - Euro Members"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "JPY - Japan Yen"
}]
}
```

How can i achieve this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views, where you are returning that result, just wrap it in the desired form;

```
return Response({
    "country-codes": [response]
})
```

Where

```
response = {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "USD - United States Dollar"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "EUR - Euro Members"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "JPY - Japan Yen"
    }
```

Comment: I got it.  Thanks for instant response

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted and leave an upvote if it helped. Thanks!